# Book recommendation for Axiomatic three-dimensional geometry and analytic geometry

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation, axiomatic-geometry

I'm reading John Lee's book Axiomatic Geometry and I enjoy it a lot. It includes a detailed treatment of Euclidean plane geometry with rigorous proofs from axioms.

I'm looking for books about Euclidean three-dimensional geometry and Cartesian coordinate system (Analytic geometry) with a similar level of rigour as John Lee's Axiomatic Geometry. The pre-requisites should also be similar to that for John Lee's Axiomatic Geometry.